# Do comments get translated to machine code? C++

Tags: c++, performance, compilation, comments, compiler-optimization

When a program written in C++ has comments, are those comments translated into machine language or do they never get that far?  If I write a C++ program with an entire book amount of comments between two commands, will my program take longer to compile or run any slower?

Comment: There is nothing in Standard C++ that dictates comments be translated to machine code or stored in the binary in any way, instead they are simply ignored.

Comment: Do you expect your comments to affect your program's execution in any way?

Comment: I do of course understand that comments do not effect program execution. I just wondered if they were translated into machine language as something like `IGNORE_THIS_LINE` in binary.  Thank you both for your answers.

Comment: But assembly code may contain plenty of comments. They maybe inter-listed source code(which may contain the comments that are close source lines), compiler generated information like instruction timing, register usage, code size....So, sort of, yes, as if you say assembly is machine language.

Comment: Comments in assembly language are not present in the executable.

Comment: Visual C+ has `#pragma comment` which indicates that Visual C++ should leave a comment in the generated object file.  So if you really wanted to put a comment in there...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Comments are normally stripped out during preprocessing, so the compiler itself never sees them at all.

They can (and normally do) slow compilation a little though--the preprocessor has to read through the entire comment to find its end (so subsequent code will be passed through to the compiler. Unless you include truly gargantuan comments (e.g., megabytes) the difference probably won't be very noticeable though.

Although I've never seen (or heard of) a C or C++ compiler that did it, there have been compilers (e.g., for Pascal) that used specially formatted comments to pass directives to the compiler. For example, Turbo Pascal allowed (and its successor probably still allows) the user to turn range checking on and off using a compiler directive in a comment. In this case, the comment didn't (at least in the cases of which I'm aware) generate any machine code itself, but it could and did affect the machine code that was generated for the code outside the comment.

Answer (score 8):

No, they are simply ignored by the compiler. Comments' sole purpose is for human reading, not machine.

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor eliminates comments.. Why should the compiler read them anyway? They are there to make it easier for people to understand the code..
Haven't you heard the joke "It's hard to be a comment, you always get ignored" :p

Answer (score 3):

In the **3rd translation phase**

- The **source file is decomposed into comments**, sequences of whitespace characters *(space, horizontal tab, new-line, vertical tab, and form-feed)*, and preprocessing tokens.
- **Each comment is replaced by one space** character.

See this [cpprefference article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) for more information about the phases of translation

Answer (score 1):

No , they are removed by the `preprocessor` .You can check this by using `cpp: The C Preprocessor` . Just write a simple C-program with comment and then use `cpp comment.c | grep "your comment"` .