# Is there any way to separate code and comments in program file

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to write a code and separate comments and code and store them in different files.

I have tried copying whole code into another file.
I need 2 files, one containing code and and one containing comments.

Comment: You can only do that if you make assumptions on the input. Otherwise you will get very close to writing a full parser. I assume you mean input which contains C language, but that does not matter. For all languages the answer is the same. It might however be easier for languages which only support line end comments like in C `// all of the rest of the line reliably is a comment, next line not automatically`. (Downvotes not by me by the way.)

Comment: C comments in all their glory, including trigraphs and backslash-newline handling, are remarkably complex.  Ignoring trigraphs and backslash-newline handling, they're much simpler (but not simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First research on how compiler distinguishes comments from code.

Link - [Do comments get translated to machine code? C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950718/do-comments-get-translated-to-machine-code-c)

You can strip comment from code in the same way comments are stripped before/in preprocessing.

Stripped comment before/in preprocessing - Comments in file.

Output to the preprocessing  - Code in file.