# Can we execute comment in C/CPP?

Tags: c++, c

```
//Printing something from comment
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  //This is a comment line \r printf("I am printed from comment");
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to come up with solution by adding various escape sequences present in C but it does'nt worked.

Comment: A comment is not parsed as code. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: They didn't think of questions like this when adding the minimum-size requirement for Answers

Comment: This has got to be an XY-Problem.  What's the issue behind the question ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Comments are for preventing things from being executed. So are you trying to find bugs in your compilers?

Comment: Are you expecting a special syntax inside a comment?

Comment: BTW, you have a `;` after the `#include` which is not necessary.

Comment: As we can execute a comment in java using \u000d in the comment line why not in c

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar:  Because C and Java and C++ are different languages.  Skipping comment content makes compiler writing easier.

Comment: You can escape a comment that starts with `/*` by using `*/` to escape it and `/*` to resume it. You can escape a comment that starts with `//` by using a new-line character to escape it and `//` to resume it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No I am just trying to print something from the comment line in the output screen.

Comment: @MikeCAT This might be an bug , presently just exploring the scope of comment statements.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am trying to execute through comment.

Comment: *I am trying to execute through comment*. Yes, you've said that a few times. But you have still not answered - **why**? If it should be executed why is it in a comment? And "because java can" is not a good reason. Why would you need to do that even in java?

Comment: IMHO, using conditional compilation is a lot better than commenting code.  For example, using `#if NDEBUG` or `#if LOGGING`.

Comment: In C and C++ your desire is usually accomplished using some form of *logging*.  Many logging functions write a sting to a file with a timestamp.  Others write to `stdout`.  An advantage to logging is that you get a receipt of how the program behaves; sometimes you can't get this using a debugger in debug mode (vs. optimized release) mode.

Comment: How to execute a comment: First you start by saying, "Michael Corleone says hello."

Comment: This was asked here before (in another context) but same main idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950718/do-comments-get-translated-to-machine-code-c `Comments are normally stripped out during preprocessing, so the compiler itself never sees them at all.`

Comment: @SaifeddineBenSalem yes

Answer (score 3):

> Can we execute comment in C/CPP?

No, we cannot - at least not in any standard way. Content of comments are removed in a phase of translation and as such there is no way to access that content from within the program.

C++ Standard says (latest draft):

> [lex.phases]
>
> The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by the following phases.
>
> ...
>
> 3. The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens ([lex.pptoken]) and sequences of whitespace characters (including comments).
>    A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment.
>    **Each comment is replaced by one space character.**
>    New-line characters are retained.
>    Whether each nonempty sequence of whitespace characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by one space character is unspecified.
>    The process of dividing a source file's characters into preprocessing tokens is context-dependent.
>
> ...

Comment: "The preprocessor removes all comments" Actually, the preprocessor doesn't know about comments. They are removed by the lexer, before the parsing even begins.

Comment: I'm curious too. what is a lexer ?

Comment: @SaifeddineBenSalem [Here's a good discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842809/lexers-vs-parsers).

Comment: @DarkAtom Fair enough. I'll actually add quotes from the standard in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

comment is just used for remembering what the function do and the compiler does not compile it.

Answer (score 0):

As others said comments can not be executed, the pre processor removes the line after the double slash.

However, you can do this in a psudo way with the /* */ comment style

So, Instead of

// This is a comment line \r printf("I am printed from comment");

Do

/* This is a comment line */  printf("I am printed from comment");

It isnt literally printed from the comment but you CAN have the printf visually on the same line as the comment.